# Where should the routing settings for Laravel 5.5 on Nginx be put?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am new to Nginx and have just started to give it a try on Windows using [WinNMP](https://winnmp.wtriple.com/) I have successfully installed and can play with basic PHP. Then I move on to trying Laravel 5.5. The installation using composer seems success and it gives the laravel error page:

[image]

The url I used to call this page is http://localhost/mylaraveltest/public/

I have checked the Laravel error log file but no error message there. I then checked the error message from Nginx and see this:

```
2018/03/28 11:30:20 [warn] 8560#11828: *21 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /mylaraveltest/public/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9003", host: "localhost"
2018/03/28 11:30:20 [error] 8560#11828: *21 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /mylaraveltest/public/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9003", host: "localhost"
```

It seems to be the problem related to routing problem. From the [official page](https://winnmp.wtriple.com/nginx.php#Laravel-Nginx-configuration), it seems that I should add the following:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
```

The problem is, it does not mentioned where should I put this line in.... and it seems to be so obvious that all guides I found by Google simply just focus on what to add but don't mention where to add this line.

I make a guess and put it inside the `server` bracket of `nginx.conf`, but the problem is still there. If this is the wrong place to add, where should it be put? And if this is the correct place, then what else can cause the problem?

Comment: Can u try this ?
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

Comment: First of all, am I adding the settings related to try_files correct?

Comment: I guess laravel is working fine.
can u show ur routes

Comment: i use this `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`

Comment: I mean, where should I add this line?

Comment: are u using `php artisan serve`

Comment: before this `location ~ \.php$ {}`

Comment: No. I just start my nginx server and use the url "http://localhost/mylaraveltest/public"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167692/discussion-between-jigs1212-and-cytsunny).

Answer (score 1):

The file you are looking for is (usually) located in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site00.app`

And should contain something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name .site00.app;
    root "/home/vagrant/sites/site00/site/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }



    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/site00.app-error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;


        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/site00.app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/site00.app.key;
}
```

Where `site00.app` both in the filename and in the config, is the name and tld of your application.